# Postgresql find by two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have join table tags_videos

```
 tag_id | video_id
--------+----------
   1195 |    15033
   1198 |    15033
   1199 |    15033

   1196 |    15034
   1198 |    15034
   1199 |    15034

   1197 |    15035
   1198 |    15035
   1199 |    15035

   1195 |    15036
   1197 |    15036
   1198 |    15036
```

How can I select distinct `video_id` who have two specific `tag_id`

For example my tag_ids is `1195 and 1198`, i should get video_ids `15033 and 15036` (who have 1195 and 1198 tag_id)

Comment: Do you want to find those videos that have **exactly** two tags, or those that have _at least_ two tags?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name have exactly two tags, specific ID

Comment: But both IDs have **three** different tags

Comment: So you want those that have _at least_ those two tags

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the unique (tag_id, video_id) pairs for the two tags in `t` CTE and select these `video_id`'s that have both `tag_id`'s (i.e. 2 occurrences).

```sql
with t as 
(
 select distinct tag_id, video_id
 from tags_videos 
 where tag_id in ('1195', '1198')
)
select video_id from t
group by video_id having count(*) = 2;
```

DB-fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pvw5nprqaFpKeGfWPtk7TP/0)